# spring security oauth2 + switch user filter

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I would like to set up ***SwitchUserFilter*** in my spring-boot app which implements spring-security-oauth2 yet. I've already set up this filter in my ***WebSecurityConfiguration*** that extends ***WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter***.

After login I obtain my token, a bearer token, and I use a configured endpoint to switch user.

I follow the code with debug in my IDE and apparently *SecurityContextHolder* is updated and a new target user is injected.

However, when the request is redirected to the target URL (a property of this filter), *SecurityContextHolder* gives me the old user back and not what I've requested.

I've inspected ***OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter*** and the token extracted from request return a same bearer token and with this it builds user detail and inject it into *SecurityContextHolder*.

Is there any way to use this kind of filter with oauth2 approach?

Comment: Did you get the right answer to this? please share?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you need to create a new token that contains the new target user information. This new token has to be sent back to the client, so for future requests the new target user token is used. In our case the token is persisted on the server side (using the JDBCTokenStore), but it would also work in completely server-side stateless environments (JWT-Token).

Our environment is a spring-boot/jhipster application with an angular 1.2 client.

Creating a new token:

```
@Inject
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Inject
private AuthorizationServerTokenServices tokenService;

@Inject
private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;


   public OAuth2AccessToken createImpersonationAccessToken(String login) {
       UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(login);
       log.info("Switching current user to {}", login);

       Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = userDetails.getAuthorities();
       List<GrantedAuthority> impersonationAuthorities = new ArrayList<>(authorities);
       Authentication source = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
       // add current user authentication (to switch back from impersonation):
       SwitchUserGrantedAuthority switchUserAuthority = 
               new SwitchUserGrantedAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.IMPERSONATION, source);
       impersonationAuthorities.add(switchUserAuthority);
                   UserDetails newUserDetails = 
               org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
               .withUsername(login)
               .authorities(impersonationAuthorities)
               .password("justinventedhere")
               .build();
                           Authentication userPasswordAuthentiation = 
               new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(newUserDetails, null, impersonationAuthorities);

       Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();        
       ClientDetails client = clientDetailsService.loadClientByClientId(clientId);
                   OAuth2Request oauthRequest = new OAuth2Request(parameters, client.getClientId(), client.getAuthorities(), true, 
               client.getScope(), client.getResourceIds(), null, null, null);
       OAuth2Authentication authentication = new OAuth2Authentication(oauthRequest, userPasswordAuthentiation);
       OAuth2AccessToken createAccessToken = tokenService.createAccessToken(authentication);
                   return createAccessToken;
   }
```

This new token is returned to the client (in our case an angular 1.2 application) that stores the token in its local storage (to be used on next requests). Then the application needs reloading (simplest way to update the target user):

```
vm.switchToClient = function (client) {
    vm.switchingUser = true;
    UserService.switchToClient(client, function(response) {
                var expiredAt = new Date();
                $localStorage.authenticationToken = response;
                window.location.href='#/';
                window.location.reload()
            });
}
```

Comment: Man please share full info.

Answer (score 0):

You could inject your own AuthenticationManager and override the behavior

```
private class AuthenticationManager extends OAuth2AuthenticationManager {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        Authentication currentAuthentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (currentAuthentication instanceof UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) {
            for (GrantedAuthority ga : currentAuthentication.getAuthorities()) {
                if (ga instanceof SwitchUserGrantedAuthority) {
                    SwitchUserGrantedAuthority switchedFrom = (SwitchUserGrantedAuthority) ga;
                    Authentication switchedFromSource = switchedFrom.getSource();
                    for (GrantedAuthority sf : switchedFromSource.getAuthorities()) {
                        String authority = sf.getAuthority();
                        if (switchUserAuthority.equals(authority)) {
                            return currentAuthentication;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return super.authenticate(authentication);
    }
```